# Migration of docker image from AWS to Bluemix or Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, docker, migration, ibm-cloud

I have a newbie regarding docker. I would like to know if it is possible to export a docker image created for AWS to Bluemix or Azure. My docker image contains a websocket server under NodeJS and a MongoDB database.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access your aws cloud and use:

```
docker save -o image.tar image:1.0 #exporte docker image
```

After concluded that, access your new cloud and use:

```
docker load -i image.tar #load your image to the new cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the dockerfile you used to create your AWS container, you can simply use it to build the container on Bluemix using cf ic client or the docker native one

Following the reference doc for Bluemix docker cli

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_ov.html

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html